# Convert PictureBox Crop Location to WebCam Crop Location

Tags: c#, winforms, aforge

I have my project setup so my webcam is streaming high resolution video and it's displayed in a low resolution picturebox.  The user can select a cropped area on the picturebox and I am suppose to crop the webcam image.  Since the webcam and the picturebox have different resolution, how do I convert from one to the other?

Here is a picture to illustrate, I need to find Point 3 and Point 4.  I have the information to the rest.

[image]

Here is my code that I am using to crop and save the webcam image.  Please help me fill in Point 3 and Point 4.

```
        int P1X = cropStart.X;
        int P1Y = cropStart.Y;
        int P2X = cropEnd.X;
        int P2Y = cropEnd.Y;
        int webcamWidth = WebcamLastFrame.Width;
        int webcamHeight = WebcamLastFrame.Height;
        int pnlWidth = pnlVideoPreview.Width;
        int pnHeight = pnlVideoPreview.Height;
        int P3X = 0; //?
        int P3Y = 0; //?
        int P4X = 0; //?
        int P4Y = 0; //?
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(P3X, P3Y, P4X, P4Y);
        Bitmap cropped = WebcamLastFrame.Clone(rect, WebcamLastFrame.PixelFormat);
        cropped.SetResolution(300, 300);
        cropped.Save(MainLocation + @"\capture.png");
        cropped.Dispose();
```

Comment: Isnt't it just a mathematical computation? For example, If the web cam is twice the size, multiply the x and y by 2.

Comment: It depends on the stretching mode of the PictureBox. See the dupe I marked.